# Pyuic making strange buttons

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5

Im using QT Creator to make a UI, and Pyuic5 to convert it into python. When I design it in QT Creator, it looks like this:
[image]

But when I run a simple python script that shows it, I end up with this:
[image]

Does anyone know why? To make the colours, I'm changing them on a button by button basis.

Heres the UI file [link](http://www.filedropper.com/mainwindow)

Comment: I can post the generated python if necessary, but I didnt want to make it too long.

Comment: You could share the .ui file

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: Are you using pyqt5 or pyqt4? I've tested your code and it generates the same Qt Designer output. I have not had problems, [here](https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/712d17bbe9ce0f50972b10a3593c6f49) is my code.

Comment: Try placing the fusion style with: `app.setStyle("Fusion")`

Comment: When I run your code, I get the same result, do you get a different result?

Comment: I get the same result as Qt Designer.

Comment: Ah right, when I add that style the colour works. Why does that happen?

Comment: I will publish my answer and understand you better, please mark it as correct. You could also `print(app.style())` before the code I told you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt Designer shows you a preview of the merging style, but one can change styles. The following image shows the different style that one can choose.

[image]

Many the style of qt for the Operating System does not match the one of Qt Designer, looking at the screenshot that shows after executing pyuic I think that it is the style windows that has by default your OS.

So one solution is to set the style so that it does not take the style that the OS uses.

You must place the fusion style using the following code:

```
app.setStyle("Fusion")
```